# Why can't I use two float variables in if statement?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to use this code in pine script but it can not compile and has ERROR...
And it says that I should send a bool variable to it so as not to cause a possible error
But I can't take a picture of the error, it will be deleted with a screenshot!!!

```
var float E1=na
var float E2=na
var float SL1=0
var float SL2=0
var bool waslong=na
var bool wasstop=false
var float mprice=na
```

and

```
e1=close[0]
sl1=e1*0.993
```

and

```
mprice:=close[0]
if mprice<= sl1
    wasstop:=true
```

If I use below code instead of it, all things is ok!!!

```
if close[0]<= close[5]
    wasstop:=true
```

Comment: How is `sl1` defined?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you. There is nothing wrong with comparing two float variables. So, your code must have some other issue.

Comment: I added all of codes, if you can please check it...thank you

Answer (score 0):

I change it to mprice=0 and solve it after 3 days!!
var float mprice=na